# Dynamically tell CI which database must be used

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I've developped an app using CI 3.1.0, and I'd like to make it more portable, so I've developped an Install model, called by an Install controller. Basically, when it's called, it checks if there is a DB (with the credentials provided in database.php) with a specific name. If there is not such a DB, it creates it then creates the tables inside it.

I've created a new group named `'newbase'` where the credentials are dynamically added during the install process; for instance, to give the database name, I have the following piece of code :

```
    $this->db->database = $database;
```

My problem is when I want to create the tables with the Database Forge `create_table()` method : I get an error message telling me that no DB has been selected (err 1046).

Just before creating the tables, I load the proper database and I checked if it's in use :

```
$this->load->database('newbase', TRUE);
echo "<BR>the active database is :".$this->db->database;
```

However, I still get this 1046 error. If I'm not mistaken, loading a database is equivalent to the keyword `USE`, so why my solution soesn't work ?

Thanks

Comment: $this->newDb = $this->load->database('newbase', TRUE);
Use this variable to create a new table.

Comment: from what must I call dbforge class ?

Comment: First create database using dbforge and then load the new database assign it to a new variable. Use this variable to create tables. I suggest using migrations.

Comment: That's what I've done but I can't call dbforge on the newly created object